# How to remove parent section from attachment URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, attachments, buddypress

I have buddypress installed. All URL goes under BP's URL structure. If an attachment belongs to a document in a group, the URL is:

```
http://domain.com/groups/group-name/docs/doc-name/attachment-name
```

I would like to learn how to change the attachment URL to:

```
http://domain.com/?attachment_id=123
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attachment URL is created in `wp-includes/link-template.php` in function `get_attachment_link()`. And there is a filter for you, passing the WordPress URL and the post id for the attachment. You can hook into that filter and return the URL you need:

```
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpse_56619_unprettify_attachment_url', 10, 2 );

function wpse_56619_unprettify_attachment_url( $link, $id )
{
    return home_url( "/?attachment_id=$id" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! After add the filter, what to do if I want to change /?attachment_id= to /?presentation=

Comment: Almost impossible. That string is hard coded all over the place in core. It is also used in POST requests, so a simple rewrite rule will not do it.

Comment: Thanks for making this crystal clear! I've tried all tips I found on the net.